# Javascript - Polygon line intersect

Tags: javascript, line, polygon, formula, intersection

I have an array in Javascript with x and y coordinates that represents a polygon, for example:

`var coords = [ [100, 150], [100, 200], [150, 200], [150, 150], [100, 150] ];`

I need to check if the lines of the polygon intersect with each other but I can't figure out how.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80798/detecting-polygon-self-intersection

Comment: This Javascript library may also be useful: http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/